# Trying to run beautifulsoup4, nead help or suggest another way to parse website data

Tags: parsing, web, request, beautifulsoup, scrape

I intalled python requests correctly (just dragged the folder into Lib folder), but I went to install BeautifulSoup and kept getting the error below. I tried doing a pip install, I thought it was successful but I am a novice and it was a bit confusing.

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bs4
  File "C:\Python34\lib\bs4\__init__.py", line 175
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>*
```

Can anyone help simplify this process or suggest a better way to gather data from a website.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The above code have a python 2.X syntax and you are working with python 3. Either you make a mistake in your installation or the beautifulsoup setup have a bug.

I suggest to uninstall and reinstall again using pip. Just make sure you are using the pip version of python 3.